# While populating Checkboxlist getting error nullreferenceexception was unhandled by user code ? Asp.net

Tags: asp.net, .net, ajax, updatepanel, checkboxlist

i am trying to fill checkbox list in asp.net 4.0 inside update panel my code is,

```
  <div>
                                    <asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server">
        </asp:ToolkitScriptManager>
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="updatepanel1" runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:PopupControlExtender ID="TextBox1_PopupControlExtender" runat="server" DynamicServicePath=""
                    Enabled="True" ExtenderControlID="" TargetControlID="TextBox1" PopupControlID="Panel1"
                    OffsetY="22">
                </asp:PopupControlExtender>
                <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" Height="116px" Width="145px" BorderStyle="Solid"
                    BorderWidth="2px" Direction="LeftToRight" ScrollBars="Auto" BackColor="#CCCCCC"
                    Style="display: none">
                    <asp:CheckBoxList ID="CheckBoxList1" runat="server"  
                        DataTextField="holiday_name" DataValueField="holiday_name" AutoPostBack="True"
                        OnSelectedIndexChanged="CheckBoxList1_SelectedIndexChanged">
                    </asp:CheckBoxList>
                </asp:Panel>
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </div>
```

my code behind is as,

```
 CheckBoxList CheckBoxList1 = (CheckBoxList)Page.FindControl("CheckBoxList1");
            CheckBoxList1.DataSource = Dcon.Tables[0];
            CheckBoxList1.DataBind();
```

Dcon is dataset having values like,

```
holiday_name

mon
tue
wed
thur
```

I have not mentioned here checkboxlist1_selectedindex change event as on load it is giving error while populating checkbox list error is,

```
nullreferenceexception was unhandled by user code
```

on line,

```
 CheckBoxList1.DataSource = Dcon.Tables[0];
```

i dont know why it is giving error when dataset has data ? and i initialy find control checkbox list as it is in ajax update panel and not finding this control directly

Hopes for your suggestion thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if it is a Content page of master page 
then first..
find master page ContentPlaceHolder than find your control

```
  ContentPlaceHolder mycont = (ContentPlaceHolder)Master.FindControl("ContentPlaceHolder1");
    CheckBoxList CheckBoxList1 = (CheckBoxList)mycont.FindControl("CheckBoxList1");
    CheckBoxList1.DataSource = Dcon.Tables[0];
    CheckBoxList1.DataBind();
```